# What exact operations does an enhanced for-loop perform on a linked-list for each iteration?

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

```
for (String msg : messages) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Say that messages is a properly initialized circular, doubly linked list that has no head or end pointer (reference). That is, it just has a current node pointer. My question simply is what exactly is the enhanced for loop doing for each iteration. If necessary, I have an interface that I can post for this special type of ADT that messages is.

Here is the iterator:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedCircularSequenceIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
     private DblListnode<E> curr;
     private int itemsLeft;

  public LinkedCircularSequenceIterator(DblListnode<E> curr, int numItems) {
    this.curr = curr;
    this.itemsLeft = numItems;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return itemsLeft > 1;
  }

  public E next() {
    if(!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    curr = curr.getNext();
    itemsLeft--;

    return curr.getPrev().getData();
  }

  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code for iterator()? I suspect you'll end up with an infinite loop, unless your Iterator has special logic to detect a loop.

Comment: public Iterator<E> iterator() {
  return new LinkedCircularSequenceIterator<E>(curr, numItems);
 }

Comment: @That returns your custom iterator, I'm pretty sure xxpor wanted the code for the actual iterator, i.e: `LinkedCircularSequenceIterator<E>`

Comment: I put the implementation above

Comment: Then my answer below is what will happen. Your requirement of int numItems in the constructor essentially just says how many "eaches" there will be in the for each loop. If it's a circular list, you could specify realNumOfItems*3 and get each item 3 times.

Comment: Shouldn't `hasNext()` return `itemsLeft > 0;` instead of `itemsLeft > 1;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be doing something like

```
Iterator<Message> iter = messages.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
    msg=iter.next().toString();
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The enhanced for-loop does nothing special.
a

```
for (T i : aCollection) {
  doSomething;
}
```

simply translates to

```
for (Iterator<T> itr = aCollection.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
  T i = itr.next();
  doSomething;
}
```

How it iterate thru the collection is the work of the iterator, and it has nothing to do with the enhanced for loop.